# How to implement a multi step progress bar with a positive z-index?

Tags: html, css, sass, telerik, kendo-grid

I am working on an application that implements a multi step progress bar (please see an example [here](https://codepen.io/athimannil/pen/wWPYkQ)).  It is implemented using sass/scss as an Angular5 component.

The progress bar works great everywhere except where the component is inserted into a Kendo Grid as a Column Template.  Since the progress bar rely's on `z-index` being set to -1 for the lines between the steps, this part of the progress bar gets hidden behind the Kendo grid.

How can the same progress bar be achieved with using only positive z-index.

I have tried changing `z-index: -1` to 1 and adding `z-index:2` to other parts of the scss but I have not succeeded in hiding the line between the steps on both ::before and ::after. Changing the z-index on the Kendo grid is not an option as it breaks the functionality of the grid.  (Also, Kendo advises against it, see [here](https://www.telerik.com/forums/z-index-lower-then-window's-(not-acceptable)) )

Comment: Can you please show an actual example of the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the given example, the `z-index: -1;` is applied to the `li::after` pseudo-element, which you can increase to a higher value (for example 2).

Now, you need to increase the `z-index` of `li::before` pseudo-element to even a higher value (like 3).

Finally you need to set `position: relative;` to it, as `z-index` won't work on static elements.

Updated example [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OQJmxW)

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about position: relative;